# Fitting spans with gradients to the expected size for background colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gradient, background-color

I am working on a project for an interview where I am trying to recreate the stripe.com website using html, css, and bootstrap. However, after weeks of trying we haven't figured out how to get the spans to match what is on the stripe website.

Here is a screen shot of what I'm supposed to have:

[image]

And here is what I currently have:

[image]

I've never used spans before to build a background with different colors before so this has been a challenge for me. I have at different points had all the spans appear, but when I did, I was not able to get them the right size and/or in the right position. How do I get these spans to be 1/3 the size of the div they are in, and also how do I them positioned in the correct spot?

```css
body {
  background-color: #f6f9fc;
  font-family: Camphor, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 25px;
  /* original CSS says 62.5% */
  /* height: 25;
    width: 62;
    font-size: 62.5%; */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: bold;
  margin-right: 220px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#pricing {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  padding: auto 0;
}

#stripes {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-12deg);
  transform: skewY(-12deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #53f 15%, #05d5ff 70%, #a6ffcb 94%);
  position: relative;
  height: 760px;
}

#stripes span {
  height: 40px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#stripeSpan1 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  left: -16.66666%;
  top: 40px;
  background: #4c29ff;
}

#stripeSpan2 {
  width: 33.333333%;
  right: auto;
  left: 16.66666%;
  bottom: auto;
  background: #2be7ff;
}

#stripeSpan3 {
  width: 33.333333%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  background: #a1ffc8;
}

#stripeSpan4 {
  background: #25ddf5;
  top: 380px;
  right: -16.66666%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

#stripeSpan5 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  bottom: 0;
  background: #1fa2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg ">
            <div class='d-flex align-items-center'>
                <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">stripe</a>


                <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Developers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Company</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="pricing">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-right">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Support</a>

                    <li class="nav-item float-right">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light no-wrap" href="#">Sign In →</a>
                    </li>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
        <div id="stripes" aria-hidden="true">
            <span id="stripeSpan1"></span>
            <span id="stripeSpan2"></span>
            <span id="stripeSpan3"></span>
            <span id="stripeSpan4"></span>
            <span id="stripeSpan5"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="container-lg header-text">
            <span class="badge badge-success">NEW</span>
            <p class="float-right text-light">
                Itroducing the Corporate Card
            </p>
            <h2 class="text-light">
                The new standard in online payments
            </h2>
            <p class="text-light">
                Stripe is the best software platform for running an internet business. We handle billions of dollars
                every year
                for
                forward-thinking businesses around the world.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the CSS of the stripe.com website. You could get the exact values of the spans...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider multiple background to approximate it. Simply find the correct values to have a good result:

```css
.stripe {
  height:300px;
  background: 
    /* Color                         position     / width height */
    linear-gradient(#25dbf3,#25dbf3) center right / 30%   70px, 
   
    linear-gradient(#1fa2ff,#1fa2ff) bottom left  / 40%   70px,
    
    linear-gradient(#5533ff,#5533ff) top left     / 30%   70px,
    linear-gradient(#4553ff,#4553ff) top left     / 60%   70px,
    linear-gradient(#4f40ff,#4f40ff) top left     / 100%  70px,
    /* main background*/
    linear-gradient(150deg, #53f 15%, #05d5ff 70%, #a6ffcb 94%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:skewY(-10deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">

</div>
```